# What can scholarly dwarfs do?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The newer versions of Dwarf Fortress introduce the concept of libraries, scholars, scribes, etc. Can my new dwarf scholars actually do anything? Or do they just sit there and look <strike>pretty</strike> smart?

Answer (score 3):

The following info is from the [DF wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Scholars in fortress mode (either your dwarves, or visiting scholars) can write books on quires of paper (another new feature) and these written quires can then be transformed into books in a craftsdwarf workshop (this requires the written quire, a thread and a bookbinding [of wood, stone, glass or metal]).  As to what topics they can or may write about; see [this page](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Topic).